# I do not understand what is this syntax error in pug

Tags: pug

I think the problem is with the length. Can anyone suggest a better way to write code for this issue. I do not understand what is this syntax error in pug. Unexpected token (59:0)

```
    html
    head
    title Issue Tracker List
    body
    h3 Issue Info 
    a(href="issue/add") Add
    br
    table(border="1")
    tr
    th Id
    th Name
    th Description
    th Action

each issue in issues
    if (issue.length)
    -for (var i = 0; i < issue.length; i++)
      li= issue[i].id
    - else
      li sorry, no issues!

    tr
    td #{issue.id}
    td #{issue.name}
    td #{issue.description}
    td
    a(href="/issue/edit/"+ issue.id) Edit

a(href="/issue/delete/" + issue.id, onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')") Delete
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are multiple fatal errors in the provided code and fixing one just surfaces another.  There is no practical single answer that will fix this and it's not suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com in this state either.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in this code that would cause such a syntax error:

```
if (issue.length)
  -for (var i = 0; i < issue.length; i++)
    li= issue[i].id
  - else
    li sorry, no issues!
```

`if` is a valid pug statement, and so is `else`.  However, your else statement is [unbuffered](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) with a `-` which is going go translate into a for-else loop which doesn't exist and isn't valid.  I think this is what you want instead:

```
if (issue.length)
  -for (var i = 0; i < issue.length; i++)
    li= issue[i].id
else
  li sorry, no issues!
```

I can see other problems waiting for you once you solve this, and would strongly recommend that you do a pug tutorial (or two or three) and spend more time reading the [pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thank you, but it still throws a different error - - - - th Action 14| > 15| each issue in issues 16| if (issue.length) 17| -for (var i = 0; i < issue.length; i++) 18| li= issue[i].id Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Yes, as I noted in the answer you have multiple issues in your code.  I appreciate your conundrum, but StackOverflow limits the questions to one discrete issue each.